# No suitable method found for setString

Tags: java, stored-procedures

I'm writing a method that calls a stored procedure in a MSSQL database.
The stored procedure has 4 inputs, all numbers.
I'm using `setString()` to enter the paramaters for the stored procedure.

I'm getting the following compile error

> no suitable method found for `setString(int, int)`

It seems to want `setString(int, string)` but the parameters i need to pass are ints,not strings.

Is there a way to pass ints or do I have to convert the `int`s to `string`?

```
public void genRoadMap(int id, int semester, int debug, int units)
{
   CallableStatement c = null;
   try
   {
        c = connection.prepareCall("{call dbo.GenerateRoadMap(?, ?, ?, ?)}");
        c.setString(1, id);           
        c.setString(2,semester);
        c.setString(3,debug);
        c.setString(4,units);
        c.execute();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to pass integers, perhaps [`setInt(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt(int,%20int)) would be more appropriate? No need to [force a square peg into a round hole](http://richardwiseman.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/square-peg-round-hole.jpg). Unless it's fun, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the `int`s to a `String` if that's what the method signature expects.  You can use the [`String.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) method to accomplish this.

To address what you said in the comment: if you are attempting to have the *procedure* process the data as an `int`, you need to pass the data in as such using the appropriate method in `CallableStatement` (in this example, [`setInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)).

Comment: will that work if the stored procedure has parameters of type int?

Comment: If you want to set an `int` for the proc, use `setInt()` as opposed to `setString()`.  You have to use the appropriate method for your data type.

Answer (score 2):

```
c.setInt(1, 100); // For integers
c.setString(2, "string"); // For strings
c.setDate(3, new Date()); // For dates
```